# XML sitemap generators not working?

Tags: xml, sitemap

So I have my own website, hosted in ipage.com, with the domain http://www.criticaldesigns.org

And I wanted to have a sitemap, both a xml and a static version for my website, and there are tons of awesome XML sitemaps generators, and I tried lots of them, but they all seem to give me the same result, which is an empty xml file, and when I look at the pages it says the website as 0 pages...

Does my website lack something that makes XML sitemap generators unable to find any pages or content to generate the file?

Thanks for reading.

Generators used:

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

http://www.web-site-map.com/

http://xmlsitemapgenerator.org/

etc...

Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
      http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

</urlset>
```

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/download/criticaldesigns.9427027/sitemap.html?view=1

http://xmlsitemapgenerator.org/free/getfile.aspx?job=83ef1990-0393-4cc8-961a-a6e2c9d22fc5&type=v&file=htm

Can anyone help? If any extra information is necessary, please ask, I really want to fix this issue...

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use of off-site resources to generate sitemaps. Only questions about programming are on-topic here.

Comment: Kinda, mostly my question is about website programming to, I mean, I want to know what does my website code has to have in order for a sitemap generator to work, basically my website has some issue that is preventing it to happen... I just really need help, my hosting company was not able to help me at all...

Answer (score 1):

Access to your website is restricted somehow. Check your webserver's settings.

P.S. HEAD request returns *403 Forbidden* response. POST request returns the following:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Length: 5083
X-Iinfo:
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information, I will contact my host and see what can be done towards that. Also, my website is protected with SiteLock, could it have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Contacted the host.
Seems that this problem has no solution, they have no idea either...

I manually made my own sitemap, and submitted to google webmasters, but they can't access robots.txt and say my website has 0 content, but it seems there is nothing I can do.

Thanks to everyone anyway :)